# OneHotEncoder fit error ValueError: could not convert string to float: b

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(dtype=np.str)
enc.fit([['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'd', 'f']])
print enc.transform([['a', 'd', 'f']]).toarray()
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: b

sklearn.**version** = 0.19.2

It can't work too if dtype = np.int64

Comment: I just uninstalled 0.21.3 and installed 0.19.2 and got the same error your getting. if you try uninstalling than pip3 install scikit-learn==0.21.3  it should work

Comment: oneHotEncoder is supposed to return dummy variables, hence we cann't expect it to return str format as output.

Comment: It is accepted in sklearn 0.21, thanks all

Answer (score 0):

dtype in OneHotEncoder is used for desired output and only number type is supported and you are passing np.str thats why you are getting error

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(dtype = 'int64') #by default dtype is float 
enc.fit([['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'd', 'f']])
print(enc.transform([['a', 'd', 'f']]).toarray())
#op
[[1 0 0 1 0 1]]
```

Comment: dtype = np.int64  is also working , i am using sklearn version  '0.20.2' ..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
enc = enc.fit([['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'd', 'f']])
enc.data #--> array(['1.0', '1.0', '1.0'], dtype='<U32')
enc.data.tolist()
```

Comment: I'm running  sklearn.__version__                                                                                                                                                              , '0.21.3' i think you may have a bug in your version, it works on 0.21.3. Are you able to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

OneHotEncoder expects your input data to be in the numerical format before converting them to dummy variables. Thus, you might want to fit_transform using LabelEncoder to convert your categorical data to numbers first.

Another neater way to do this is using LabelBinarizer, which works like using LabelEncoder and then OneHotEncoder:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
encoder = LabelBinarizer()
encoder = encoder.fit(['a', 'd', 'f'])
print(encoder.transform(['a','d','f']))
```

Answer (score 0):

I get correct output using sklearn 0.21, it should be problem for sklearn's version, thanks all !